# is it possible to run process that use only 2 CPU from 16 CPU in my linux machine

Tags: linux, cpu-architecture, proc

is it possible to run process that use only 2 CPU from 16 CPU in my linux machine

we have red-hat machine version 6 and we have 16 CPU

but because license cost money and if we limit the script that will run only on 2 CPU then we can save the money

Comment: Be careful.  If you do use such limits, are you still violating your software's license? You might be. Depending on how the license is worded, you might still be violating your license to run the software on two CPUs if you run it on a 16-CPU machine, even if you limit it to only two CPUs.  It might even be worded the other way: it may license you to run on two CPU sockets - in which case, you may have only two four-core sockets, with each of the 8 CPUs being hyperthreaded so they show up as 16 logical CPUs.  If that's true, you can run on all 16.  **Read your license carefully**.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/setting-processor-affinity-certain-task-or-process.html

Comment: Create a vm and assign only 2 cpu to it?

Comment: Please provide details on the hardware, software, OS version/distribution and anything else. Otherwise, people were will be guessing about the specifics of your situation. Per-core licensing is common, but if you provide _details_, people may be able to respond with their specific workarounds and solutions.

Comment: disable the cores in bios might help for the license.